# How do I use Spaces to "save" a specific browser page on restart?

Tags: spaces

Let's say I'd like gmail.com open on my Desktop 1, and yahoo.com open on my Desktop 2 on a computer restart. Is this possible with Mac Spaces + some browser settings?

Comment: Spaces just doesn't work that way, I'm afraid. It's not designed to spread an app over more than one Space. You'd have to use two browsers for that to work seamlessly. [This is not including using apps in fullscreen, which breaks Spaces entirely & cannot be numbered]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the latest Mac OS X (Monterey) does support this for my needs!

I'm not sure if this setting is still needed (found on an older thread):

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSWindowRestoresWorkspaceAtLaunch -bool YES
```

1. Disabled all of the checked options under Mission Control.
2. Set up each space with its own Google Chrome with the website I want
3. On restart, keep the checked option for the Mac to reopen the same windows

Note: this worked for Preview as well - I have a document open to the second chapter on my 3rd Screen and successive restarts kept its place!

Comment: Glad you found it, but that's a Chrome `default` not an OS `default`. I don't have Monterey yet, but it would be good if they actually *did* implement it system-wide.